# Can you recommend some light siver colors in rgb format?

Tags: fonts, colors, photoshop

Can you recommend some light siver colors in rgb format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ask people to recommend a color - it is subjective and what appeals to one person will be hated by another. In fact, two people looking at the same color will see it *slightly* differently (although just how differently is still being scientifically debated).

Browse through the various color lookup sites out there on teh interweb. My personal favorite is [Name that color](http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of many [RGB color charts](http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/) on the Internet.